# Mongoose hanging on disconnect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose application that is running a scheduled task on a periodic basis. Unfortunately, after the first time this is run, the whole task hangs just before closing and doesn't ever run again.

Even more surprising, after commenting it down to almost nothing, it still hangs. At this point our program looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var config = require('../lib/config');
var log = require('../lib/custom-log');

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log("Mongoose connection error: " + err);
    mongoose.disconnect();
});

db.once('open', function() {
    console.log("db is open");
    mongoose.disconnect();
});

db.once('close', function() {
   console.log("db is closed");

});

mongoose.connect(config.database.uri);
```

Results in:

> db is open
>
> db is closed

Then hangs.

We run Node 0.10.36 on Ubuntu 14.10 and we connect to a 3-node replicaset via a MongoDB URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was involved in solving this problem, so, I will answer what caused it and file a bug report with Mongoose.

The issue was caused by 2 out of the 3 nodes getting suddenly out of the replica set, but they were still in the MongoDB URI. So, everything was working fine, no errors were triggered, but Mongoose (or maybe the MongoDB driver) were hanging on disconnect, because of those 2 nodes instead of raising an exception and giving clues to developers on what's broken.